# Android Crashlytics not logging non-fatals

Tags: android, exception, crash-reports, crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm logging crashlytics errors in fabric. It works for crashes, and auto-generated non-fatals. But when I try to manually log non-fatals, it doesnt show at all. What can be the problem? (Yes, I have re-opened the app after the logging).

The logging methods I have tried:

```
Crashlytics.log(message);

Crashlytics.getInstance().core.logException(exception); //Caught exception

Crashlytics.logException(exception); //Caught exception

Crashlytics.logException(new Throwable(message));
```

None of them show up in my fabric dashboard...

I instantiate Fabric with this and its logging crashes, so I don't think that's the problem.

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

Comment: `Crashlytics.logException(exception)` should do it. Usually there is a limit to number of non fatals that it records. Is none of them showing? `For any individual app session, only the most recent 8 logged exceptions are stored.` https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics/caught-exceptions.html

Comment: None are logged. Absolutely none. Not one. We have 70k daily users, so its definitively not working.

Comment: I see. And as you've shown in the question, you've tried forcing a non-fatal crash. And I assume your filter is of last 90 days? Which version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: Forced crash: Yes
Filter: Yes
SDK version: classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.22.1'

Comment: I have set to 1.23.0 and it works fine. Try updating it and maybe make sure you have `ext.enableCrashlytics = true`. Or atleast not set to false in `build.gradle`. Else open a bug report to them probably.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Will try the changes you prepose. :)

Comment: BTW: How do you instantiate Crashlytics in your app?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Can you share your app's package name?

Comment: Hey Mike! Its 'com.norwegian.travelassistant', could you contact me on mail: travelassistantATnorwegian.com ?

Comment: @MikeBonnell Did you check it?

Comment: Sorry, I missed your ping back! I'll follow up over email.

Comment: I dont know why, but it suddenly worked. Thanks to @MikeBonnell for reaching out to help. :)

Comment: @Otziii can you please share how you are able to see the logs in your Crashlytics dashboard ?

Comment: @Neha I did not do anything specific, it just worked after some time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, it's working code from my projects.

```
try {
    //your codes                    
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    Crashlytics.log("log something");//Optional
    Crashlytics.setString("message", message);//Optional
    Crashlytics.logException(ex);

}
```

Comment: As said in the question, this is what I have tried. Dont know why its failing, but cant see any instances of non-fatals at all.

Comment: @Otziii did you tried using .log() or .setString() before
Crashlytics.logException(ex);

Answer (score 5):

In Crashlytics BETA in firebase console 'Crashes only' events displayed by default. If you want view non-fatal events you must select 'All events' or 'Non-fatals only'.

Maybe it can help in Fabric console.

P.S. I don't worked with fabric without firebase.